# How do I get the 48 least significant bits of a long formatted as hex?

Tags: .net, string-formatting

```
long number = …;

// string should contain exactly 12 characters
string leastSignificant48bitsOfNumberAsHex = number.ToString("????")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with string formatting:

```
string leastSignificant48bitsOfNumberAsHex = String.Format("{0:X012}", number & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF);
```

This will fill up the string with zeroes if the number is shorter.

Comment: This doesn't work… it just gives me the same as number.ToString()

Comment: The .ToString() call (on the masked number) should be removed; use String.Format("{0:X012}", number & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF);

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to remove the `.ToString()` call when editing the answer...